# Django create different user profile instances on user signup

Tags: django

I have a Django application where there will be two types of user signups. 
`Consumers` and `Providers`.

```
class ConsumerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # Some fields


class ProviderProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # Some fields


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created: # What should the condition be here so that only the correct profile is created
        ConsumerProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

How do I make sure that when a user is created, only the correct profile model instance is created?

Comment: Why not include a `kind=UserTypes.CONSUMER` parameter or something similar in your function?

Comment: @camdenb, I'm not really sure where that would be put in. Can you please explain it a bit futher?

Comment: The `UserTypes` isn't necessary as you can always just pass a string (`kind="Consumer"`) to the function, the former is just less prone to typos. I'm afraid I don't fully understand your question, though. When would you be calling `create_user_profile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signals is not the right way to handle this. The correct way is to add this logic in your signup function:

```
def sign_up(request):
   form = SignupForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
   if form.is_valid():
      user = User.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data['usern_name'],
                                      form.cleaned_data['email'],
                                      form.cleaned_data['password'])
      user.save()
      if form.cleaned_data['user_type'] == 'consumer':
         profile = ConsumerProfile()
         profile.some_field = 'some_value'
      if form.cleaned_data['user_type'] == 'provider':
         profile = ProviderProfile()
         profile.some_field = 'some_value'
      if profile:
         profile.user = user
         profile.save()
      user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a flag to your function and use it to determine the type of the user you want to create. Use an if-block to create different Profiles. Something like this:

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, consumerOrProvider, **kwargs):
    if consumerOrProvider == ENUM_CONSUMER:
        ConsumerProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    elif consumerOrProvider == ENUM_PROVIDER:
        ProviderProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

But why do you want to use a single function for this? Why not use two functions and send the correct request?

Comment: Does the User itself know what kind of profile it needs? How do you generally know which kind of profile to look for each user? If User indeed has some kind of flag to determine that, you can use it for your if condition.